# Non-linear fit Gnu Octave

Tags: regression, octave, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have a problem in performing a non linear fit with Gnu Octave. Basically I need to perform a global fit with some shared parameters, while keeping others fixed.
The following code works perfectly in Matlab, but Octave returns an error

> error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 34x1, op2 is 4x1)

Attached my code and the data to play with:

```
clear
close all
clc
pkg load optim
D = dlmread('hd', ';'); % raw data
bkg = D(1,2:end); % 4 sensors bkg
x = D(2:end,1); % input signal
Y = D(2:end,2:end); % 4 sensors reposnse
W = 1./Y; % weights
b0 = [7 .04 .01 .1 .5 2 1]; % educated guess for start the fit
%% model function
F = @(b) ((bkg + (b(1) - bkg).*(1-exp(-(b(2:5).*x).^b(6))).^b(7)) - Y) .* W;
opts = optimset("Display", "iter");
lb = [5 .001 .001 .001 .001 .01 1];
ub = [];
[b, resnorm, residual, exitflag, output, lambda, Jacob\] = ...
lsqnonlin(F,b0,lb,ub,opts)
```

To give more info, giving array b0, b0(1), b0(6) and b0(7) are shared among the 4 dataset, while b0(2:5) are peculiar of each dataset.

Thank you for your help and suggestions! ;)

Raw data:

```
0,0.3105,0.31342,0.31183,0.31117
0.013229,0.329,0.3295,0.332,0.372
0.013229,0.328,0.33,0.33,0.373
0.021324,0.33,0.3305,0.33633,0.399
0.021324,0.325,0.3265,0.333,0.397
0.037763,0.33,0.3255,0.34467,0.461
0.037763,0.327,0.3285,0.347,0.456
0.069405,0.338,0.3265,0.36533,0.587
0.069405,0.3395,0.329,0.36667,0.589
0.12991,0.357,0.3385,0.41333,0.831
0.12991,0.358,0.3385,0.41433,0.837
0.25368,0.393,0.347,0.501,1.302
0.25368,0.3915,0.3515,0.498,1.278
0.51227,0.458,0.3735,0.668,2.098
0.51227,0.47,0.3815,0.68467,2.124
1.0137,0.61,0.4175,1.008,3.357
1.0137,0.599,0.422,1,3.318
2.0162,0.89,0.5335,1.645,5.006
2.0162,0.872,0.5325,1.619,4.938
4.0192,1.411,0.716,2.674,6.595
4.0192,1.418,0.7205,2.691,6.766
8.0315,2.34,1.118,4.195,7.176
8.0315,2.33,1.126,4.161,6.74
16.04,3.759,1.751,5.9,7.174
16.04,3.762,1.748,5.911,7.151
32.102,5.418,2.942,7.164,7.149
32.102,5.406,2.941,7.164,7.175
64.142,7.016,4.478,7.174,7.176
64.142,7.018,4.402,7.175,7.175
128.32,7.176,6.078,7.175,7.176
128.32,7.175,6.107,7.175,7.173
255.72,7.165,7.162,7.165,7.165
255.72,7.165,7.164,7.166,7.166
511.71,7.165,7.165,7.165,7.165
511.71,7.165,7.165,7.166,7.164
```

Giving the function definition above, if you call it by F(b0) in the command windows, you will get a 34x4 matrix which is correct, since variable Y has the same size.
In that way I can (in theory) compute the standard formula for lsqnonlin (fit - measured)^2

Comment: That particular error lies in your formula for `F`. The variable `bkg` is a vector of length 4, whereas `W` and `Y` are vectors of length 34, so you can't multiply either `W` or `Y` by `bkg`.

Comment: @HowardRudd after changing the data delimiter from `,` to `;` and then removing the \ after Jacob, the code did run fine in Matlab 2022b.  any thoughts on why Octave has a problem with that function but matlab doesn't?  calling F(b0) works fine for both programs.

Comment: Also, W and Y are each 34x4, so they could broadcast if orientations are correct.

Comment: adding on - i notice that both programs work fine if I call F(b0). if I call F(b0'), i get the same nonconformant arguments error as when running lsqnonlin. I'm wondering if Octave's lsqnonlin has an internal orientation issue with b as it is iterating on a solution.

Comment: confirming if you dive into the subfunctions it appears that the algorithm defaults to passing a column vector of b values to F, no matter what shape b0 took. looking at the matlab help, it specifies that it uses the shape of b0 to determine what shape F takes.  it may be this has changed since Octave's lsqnonlin was written to be compatible, but I haven't confirmed that.  In any case, if you can rewrite F to be compatible with a column vector for b, then Octave should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: bug report filed at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?63708

Comment: I also missed that you posted this problem over at https://octave.discourse.group/t/non-linear-fit-with-shared-parameters/3870 .  the solution given there is to edit `F` by replacing `b(2:5) .* x` with `b(2:5)(:).' .* x`  .  That should ensure you get row vector behavior without any appreciable overhead, and should work in either Octave or MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you @NickJ for your precious help and research.
As you mentioned above, I found the solution by resizing my arrays, but cool that you report the bug.
Very appreciated! ;) thank you for your help!!

Comment: @NickJ You are right. It didn't occur to me to evaluate `F` by itself without feeding it into the `lsqnonlin` function. If I had I would have found that it evaluates correctly thereby implying that the error lies in the `lsqnonlin` function.